# Find full path names of (.BMP) files under folder, append to file

Tags: shell, find, append

I have 11 **.bmp** images in a folder. I wanted to create a text file in which each line is the *full path of an image name*.
I used the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
find -type f -iname "*.bmp" | while read x; do
    echo $(cd $(dirname "$1") && pwd -P)/$(basename "$1") >>test2.txt 
    app=$( printf "%05d" ${i}).bmp
    #echo $app
    echo $(sed '${s/$/'"${app}"'/;}'  test2.txt) 
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

...but it does not work.
 All of images are in this path: /home/behzad/Desktop/test/
I want a text file,each line like this : /home/behzad/Desktop/test/00000.bmp 
/home/behzad/Desktop/test/00001.bmp
...
/home/behzad/Desktop/test/00011.bmp

Comment: I want something like this: /home/behzad/Desktop/test/00000.bmp

Comment: Which implementation of `find` to you have? If you have GNU `find`, you can tell it to use whatever format string you want yourself.

Comment: BTW, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds before asking questions here. Also, describing what "working" means **in detail, in the question** would be helpful -- we know what your code does from reading it, but what you *want it to do* only you can say.

Comment: ...re: your first comment, you want something like `/home/behzad/Desktop/test/00000.bmp` where `/home/behzad/Desktop/test` is what? Current location of the file? Directory given as an argument to the script? Something else? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- a code sample should include **everything needed to reproduce a problem**. In this case, that means creating a temporary directory with some dummy filenames in it, and showing the output that should be generated with those specific dummy names when the script is called with a specific command line.

Comment: BTW, you might also want to take a look at BashFAQ #100. Using `sed` and `basename` in subshells carries a significant performance penalty -- inside a loop, you're much better off using native string-manipulation primitives when you can. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100

Comment: As another aside, `printf -v app '%05d' "$i"` is vastly more efficient than `app=$(printf '%05d' "$i")`, since the former happens without `fork()`ing off a child process of the shell to run the command substitution in. (Yes, it means you need to do the append separately... but given the amount of overhead we're talking, it's worth it).

Comment: @ Charles: All of images are in  /home/behzad/Desktop/test/. I want a text file,each line like this :  /home/behzad/Desktop/test/00000.bmp , /home/behzad/Desktop/test/00001.bmp,...,/home/behzad/Desktop/test/00011.bmp

Answer (score 2):

Print full path names of all `.bmp` files in `~/foo/bar` and subdirs, to new output file `test2.txt`:

```
s=~/foo/bar    # full path of dir to be searched.
find "$s" -iname "*.bmp" -type f -fprint test2.txt
```

Append more names to `test2.txt` from different directory:

```
s=~/oof/rab    # full path of dir to be searched.
find "$s" -iname "*.bmp" -type f >> test2.txt
```

Comment: I don't think that's actually what the OP is trying to do, though. Note how they're creating a counter and using it in formatting the new names.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that may well be true.  Given the OP code quality, my inference is that the OP may be somewhat confused.

Comment: No question that they're confused, but the `printf '%05d'` didn't come out of nowhere, and nor did the counter stored in `$i` -- see also the 5-digit number in their sole comment giving any insight into desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it is done :)

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
find -type f -iname "*.bmp" | while read x; do
    echo $(cd $(dirname "$1") && pwd -P)/$(basename "$1") >>test1.txt 
    app=$( printf "%05d" ${i}).bmp
    echo $app >>test2.txt
    i=$((i+1))
done

paste -d "" test1.txt test2.txt > path.txt
```

Comment: A loop sets _$x_ with filenames, but _$x_ is never used.   _test1.txt_ is a list that repeats the full path of _$1_; _test2.txt_ is a list of {00001.bmp, ... n.bmp).   Then _test1.txt_ and _test2.txt_ are pasted together, creating _path.txt_ -- those filenames may not exist, (or may), but there are as many as there are `.bmp` files under the current directory.  It makes me feel like a driving instructor on a '60s sitcom.